# Select datetime in postgres

Tags: postgresql, datetime, select

Must be missing something very simple here.  Maybe someone can answer this.  You want to select from a datetimestamp to now.  Why would the where clause return nothing with this?

```
select * from xyz where ('2020-01-29 04:18:00-06'::timestamptz > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

when

```
select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
       current_timestamp
-------------------------------
 2020-01-29 04:47:06.011133-06
(1 row)

Time: 0.258 ms
```

Should not be that hard in PostgreSQL to get every row from a certain time to current time to see what has been added or new / changed.

I found the answer to this problem with the help here.  First try I did not post was using between.  It should have been used like this.  Need to remove timestamp from the where clause and use BETWEEN!

```
TABLENAME.COL-NAME-FOR-TIMESTAMP BETWEEN '2020-01-29 04:18:00-06' AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

TABLENAME.COL-NAME-FOR-TIMESTAMP should be your column in the table you are referencing for datetime.

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: Well, `04:18` is not greater than `04:47` so the condition is not fulfilled.

Comment: How would you get ever row after 2020-01-29 04:18:00-06 up to the current time?

Answer (score 0):

The explanation is that your current timestamp, in the time zone of your Postgres server, is past 4:18am on January 29, 2020.  Try setting your time zone to something which should make your current query pass, e.g.

```
SET timezone = 'America/Los_Angeles';  -- 2:58 AM as of the time this answer was posted
SELECT * FROM xyz WHERE '2020-01-29 04:18:00-06'::timestamptz > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

I suspect that the doubt here is that you are expecting your Postgres server to be set to a certain time zone, so you should look into this.

Comment: timezone is set to 6 just like the timezone and all the data I am trying to reference...everything is in 6.... What I am trying to figure out is why the results come back as zero when their are many rows that's effective... timestamptz should convert to something that can be compared to current_timestamp... I do not understand why this dose not work...

Comment: `4:18` AM is earlier than `4:47` AM

Comment: Would would be the solution to get all results after a certain time to current time?

Comment: Use `BETWEEN <some_time> AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP`

Comment: BETWEEN '2020-01-29 04:18:00-06'::timestampz AND CURRENT_TIMESTAMP returns an ERROR at the start of the fixed date!  That was my first try a few days ago too.